# Problem to navigate between fragments in Navbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-graph

i have a problem with navigation between fragments in Navbar.
This is my situation:
I have 3 main fragments: **Home**, **List**, **Settings**
**Home** has 2 sub fragment: Add & Edit
So, if i navigate between the 3 main fragments with navbar is everything ok, then if i go in one of 2 "sub fragments" and then, (instead of "navigate up" before and then change main) i directly choose one of other 2 "main" i will go there, but then if i come back to List i will see the sub fragment.
I have to Navigate Up to see again **List**.
**What i want is **if i switch main fragment when im inside of one of the "subs"(son of **List**), and then again i choose List, i want see List and not the sub that i left.

My Code:

Navigation

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.somi.fidelitycardconnect.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:name="com.somi.fidelitycardconnect.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="Impostazioni"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:name="com.somi.fidelitycardconnect.ui.list.ListFragment"
    android:label="Lista clienti"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_addFormFragment"
        app:destination="@id/addFormFragment" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_editFormFragment"
        app:destination="@id/editFormFragment" />

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/addFormFragment"
    android:name="com.somi.fidelitycardconnect.ui.form.AddFormFragment"
    android:label="Aggiungi cliente"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_form">
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/editFormFragment"
    android:name="com.somi.fidelitycardconnect.ui.form.EditFormFragment"
    android:label="Informazioni cliente"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_form">
</fragment>
```

MainActivity:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.listFragment,
                R.id.settingsFragment
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GDr5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWfNQ.png)

**What i want is **if i switch main fragment when im inside of one of the "subs"(son of **List**), and then again i choose List, i want see List and not the sub that i left.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to press one of the `bottomNav` items and start with the default position, you need to pop the other destinations. Use below code to achieve it:

```
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)
            true
        }
```